# What's the bull's-eye?

Tags: smite

It seems to appear when facing Vulcan, i.e. it only appears on gods on the team opposing Vulcan. It looks like this:

[image: Ra marked by bull's-eye]
Image taken from a [past broadcast of Spooh](http://www.twitch.tv/spoohtheone/b/512110225?t=36s).

My best guess is that it marks gods targeted by Vulcan's Inferno Cannon turret, but I'm not sure that I haven't seen it when a turret wasn't out.

Update: So, if it is turret target, there's a delay on when the mark dissipates after being unable to be targeted by the turret.

[image: Tyr marked by bull's-eye outside of turret range]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target appears after they are hit by Vulcan's backfire (his 1). The god gets marked for 4 seconds and if they are in range of Vulcan's turret it automatically starts shooting at it and deals 10% bonus damage.

[source here](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Vulcan)

Answer (score 1):

The mark is a debuff from Vulcan's Backfire ability.  When a "marked" god is within range of Vulcan's turret, they become the turret's primary target.  The marked god also takes additional damage from the turret.